# No module name "flask_mysql"

Tags: python

I'm using Windows, using PyCharm and my code is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging
from flask_mysql import MySQL
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from passwords import _mysql_pasword
app= Flask(__name__)
```

After running this code getting the error:
**No module name "flask_mysql"**

I've installed Flask to my system still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you install the flask into a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) or system-wide? If it's installed in a virtual environment, you will need to activate it to use it.

Comment: have you installed the flask-mysql package as well? Also according to the documentation you should include it with ["flaskext.mysql"](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @rushas Yes I've installed packages and i didn't install the flask into VE

Comment: @LaibaKhan Try typing `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze` on your console/cmd/terminal. You should be able to see a list of all the installed packages and should be able to locate the `flask_mysql` if it's already installed.

Comment: @rushas I'm seing Flask-MySQL==1.5.2
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0

Comment: Could you please update the question with including the full Traceback error message(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install : pip install flask-mysql

try this :

from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

It will work for you
Thank you

Comment: Now I am taking another example. It is usefull for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need **Flask-MySQLdb** then according to it's [documentation](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can import it by

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

But if you need **Flask-MySQL** then, again as per [documentation](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can import it by

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Comment: could not locate flash application it says

Comment: what is the name of the file where you have the code?

Comment: app.py bchain is the name of the folder

Comment: "could not locate flash application it says": Are you sure this is not due to a typo?
Can you copy paste the enitre error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'

Comment: Have you installed flask-mysqldb by running "pip install flask-mysqldb"?